# Juniper EX - disable multiple interfaces at the same time as a once off

Tags: juniper-junos, juniper-ex

I have used the Cisco interface range commands on many occasions to disable  a large number of switching ports when the device is originally deployed as a once off and am looking for something similar in Junos.

I **don't** want to use **apply-groups** or the juniper **interface-range** command set as there changes are permanent and to be honest  it would confuse the Tier-1 / Tier 2 staff , aka inherited config is hidden by default and therefore will likely get missed when troubleshooting.

I am just looking for verification that there is no way to do this natively before I look at using slax to create a custom command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's supported natively.

Fortunately you don't need to create the SLAX script yourself, as such [script](https://code.google.com/p/junoscriptorium/source/browse/trunk/library/juniper/commit/interfaces/expand-interface-ranges/expand-interface-ranges.slax) already exists. Essentially you configure normal interface-range, but upon commit its content is expanded to the real interfaces and the interface-range config is removed, creating approximation of the IOS behavior.

Comment: OMG ... that's awesome I cant stop testing all the various scripts now .. I can confirm the above script does exactly what I need if you use it within context ..... just one note , you need to copy the script to all VC members e.g. "file copy /var/db/scripts/commit/expand-interface-ranges.slax fpc0:/var/db/scripts/commit/"

Answer (score 6):

Starting with JunOS 12.1 there is wildcard range set in edit mode. You can use it with various range formats, as a starting point ["Wildcard range commands for EX switches"](http://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB23789) is a good read.